# fl studio + wine = CPU overload, why?

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, acer, aspire, cpu-architecture

I've installed Ubuntu 14, 15 and mate only to find that when I run fl studio through wine it max's out the CPU when I try the free track at the beginning of the program. My laptop is an Acer aspire e5-521 with a a6 chip and 6gb of ram. Please help as I don't wanna go back to windows 8.1/poop lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always expect performance loss (at best, and total incompatibility at worst) when running anything over Wine.  In some cases the performance impact is small enough not to matter, but in others it will be significant enough to make the software near-useless.

Your options:

- Check the WineHQ database to see if anyone has tips for getting FL Studio to run better.
- Dual-boot with Windows for when you want to run FL Studio.
- Find an alternative to FL Studio that runs natively in Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately, there really is not a good alternative. Your commercial options are energyXT (reportedly unmaintained, buggy), Bitwig (web activation) or Renoise (tracker). Open-source options tend to be pretty poor in 2017; Ardour and Qtractor are the "best" and those aren't even customizable enough to replicate simple things like FL Studio's right-click-to-delete-notes. LMMS is probably the closest since it was meant to be a FL clone, although that one has trouble actually working with the rest of the linux audio ecosystem.

Comment: For audio production, Linux isn't a very good choice. I'd either dual boot Windows or work with OSX. Nearly all of decent music recording software is proprietary, and the free or open source ones are simply no good. That's because of the fact of life that intersection of Linux geeks (mostly engineers and programmers) and audio geeks is a tiny amount of people. And due to the small market segment, there isn't enough demand or motivation to push a company to create a top notch music workstation software for Ubuntu for free. Not anytime soon.